# I am trying to deploy my node js app to heroku but I keep getting an error when pushing to master

Tags: node.js, git, heroku

I am trying to deploy my node js app to heroku but I keep getting an error when pushing to master. It about Fetching set buildpack

```
git push heroku master
remote: Compressing source files... done.
remote: Building source:
remote: 
remote: -----> Fetching set buildpack https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-nodejs.git... done
remote: 
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to detect set buildpack https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-nodejs.git
remote: More info: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/buildpacks#detection-failure
remote: 
remote: Verifying deploy...
remote: 
remote: !   Push rejected to accessmusic.
remote:
```

package.json file

```
{
"name": "Access",
"version": "0.0.0",
"main": "server.js",
"private": true,
"scripts": {
"start": "node ./bin/www"
},
"dependencies": {
"body-parser": "~1.13.2",
"cookie-parser": "~1.3.5",
"debug": "~2.2.0",
"express": "~4.13.1",
"jade": "~1.11.0",
"morgan": "~1.6.1",
"serve-favicon": "~2.3.0"
},
"engines": {
"node": "4.0.0"
},
"keywords": [
"node",
"heroku",
"express"
]
}
```

[Image of terminal and error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vqBZA.png)

Answer (score 0):

You may be missing a package.json file that defines the npm packages you are using

Comment: Try changing "start": "node ./bin/www" to "start": "node server.js"